# not able to find comerr-dev_2.1-1.41.12-1ubuntu2_i386.deb deian

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, php-5.2

I am trying to install php-5.2.8 in Ubuntu 10.10 but installation process does not have comerr-dev_2.1-1.41.12-1ubuntu2_i386.deb and stopping my php installation

alternative I tried installing comerr-dev_2.1-1.41.14-1ubuntu3_i386.deb and comerr-dev_2.1-1.41.12-4stable1_i386.deb but its not compatible .I need comerr-dev_2.1-1.41.12-1ubuntu2_i386.deb or source code so that i can build deb from that code.

help me out .thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the link to download `comerr-dev_2.1-1.41.12-1ubuntu2_i386.deb` straight from [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/i386/comerr-dev/2.1-1.41.12-1ubuntu2) (this is for Ubuntu Maverick).

Comment: you are right man but the user needs only the link so I paste the download link address...